# Hard disk file system converted to Raw file system

Tags: filesystems, hard-drive

How to access Raw file system?

My Portable harddisk was working fine. But once I accessed it from linux terminal. And Later when try to use it in window it says `You need to format it before you can access`

In Ubuntu also when I plug it, it does not appear.

Tried to access through `chkdisk` but says Raw file system could not be processed.

Is there any way I can get back data inside it?

recovery software does not preserve folder when it recovers data. Also When I tried it it says "1 days remaining to process" nearly 350GB data.

Comment: "Raw" is not a file system, it means that Windows doesn't understand the file system that is/may be on the disk (or partition, rather). You may have some luck trying to access the data on Ubuntu, but it really depends on what you did when you "accessed" the drive earlier. First thing I'd suggest trying is to look at the output of `dmesg` on Linux when you plug in the drive.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for SuperUser or *possibly* Unix & Linux than it is here.

Comment: This is ALSO posted to Superuser. This must be closed.